# Zoom (with mouse scroll wheel) into specific area centred by the mouse cursor in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, zoom

In MapInfo Professional V11.0, on 64 bit windows 10 OS, when you zoom in using your mouse scroll wheel, it only zooms into the centre of the map shown on the screen. So if you want to zoom into a specific area, you have to zoom a bit, then pan, then zoom some more, then pan a bit more, all to ensure that the area you want to zoom into is in the centre of the screen.

But in other software, like QGIS for example, when you zoom in using the mouse scroll wheel, all you need to do is put the mouse cursor over the area you want to zoom into and then scroll.

How do you achieve this mouse centred scroll capability in MapInfo?

Edit:

As per comments, I tried Map preferences -> display but this is my window and it doesn't include the necessary option.

[image]

Comment: Which version of MapInfo are you using? And 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: 64 bit. MapInfo professional. If there is a version number, I'll have to advise it tomorrow sorry. Just updated the qn to include this info

Comment: It's MapInfo V11.0. Qn was updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 64-bit version 15.2, there is a feature which allows you to zoom to cursor location. This feature was added to MapInfo Pro 11.5 back in 2012.

According to **[this page](http://support.pitneybowes.com/VFP05_KnowledgeWithSidebarHowTo?id=kA180000000CsPkCAK&popup=false&lang=en_US)** from Pitney Bowes,

> There is now an option to allow the user to zoom in/out on a mapper
>   based on the cursor location, instead of the previous method, which
>   zoomed on the center of the mapper, regardless of cursor location.
>
> Select PRO > Options > Windows > Map Window where you will find the
>   option checkbox to enable or disable this feature:

[image]

**Edited to include T_Bacon's comment:**

This is also available in older 32-bit versions.  Go to

```
Options > Preferences > Map Window
```

Then select Mouse Wheel Zoom Based on Cursor Location.

It is definitely as early as 12.0 which is confirmed on page 110 of the [**12.0 user guide**](http://reference1.mapinfo.com/software/mapinfo_pro/english/12.0/MapInfoProfessionalUserGuide.pdf). That might be something which was added at 11.5 or 12.0. But as you don't have the option, I'm afraid you'll have to upgrade to a later version if you want it.

Comment: This also applies to older versions. I'm not sure exactly when it was added but I've currently got v12 (32-bit) and it has got this option though it is under Options > Preferences > Map Window.

Comment: @T_Bacon good point. I thought Thursday option existed in 32-bit but haven't used MapInfo for so long that I thought I was imagining things. I couldn't find it when I looked for it though.

Comment: It's MapInfo V11.0. Qn was just edited to include this detail

Comment: This feature was added to MapInfo Pro 11.5 back in 2012. We have just updated the article mentioned above to reflect this as it was a bit misleading earlier.